# What is the origin of the minhag to recite psukim having 3 words?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, shacharis-morning-prayer

A few weeks ago, I saw in a Siddur (I wish I could recall which one. It's not one of the "popular brands") a section at the end of *Shacharit* saying that there is a *minhag* to recite verses from the Torah that have exactly 3 words. I know that this is the minimum *pasuk* length. so I guess that makes the number 3 special, in some way.

What is the origin and reason of this minhag? Are there any specific groups of people who are diligent to follow this minhag?